# How to validate iteration through list = None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

How to check that iteration will not be over `None`?
I wrote the following code:

```
async def foo(categories: list=None):
    for category in categories or []:
```

Is it a good way or I can avoid somehow checking `or []` in every iteration?

Comment: `categories or []` is evaluated once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's test this out.

```
def foo():
    print('In foo')
    return range(5)
```

Now, if I call `foo` in the head of a `for` loop (`for _ in foo()`), it should print `In foo` as many times as it is called/evaluated.

So,

```
for _ in foo():
    pass
```

```
In foo
```

And is called just once. Meaning it was evaluated only once.